# Split LaTeX paragraphs into new lines after each sentence - re-formatting tool for VCS

Tags: parsing

> I think this question has relevance and overlap on both stack-overflow and  TeX forums, but suspect the TeX community might be better suited, so have posted it here.

## My text/tex files need reformatting

I have been writing my thesis and have sadly gotten into the bad and unsustainable habit of writing all my paragraphs on a single line.
While this has been not too much of an inconvenience, when it comes to merging or cross collaboration, it is a nightmare.
**I would like to reformat my tex files so that each sentence is started on a new line.** (As encouraged [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6154202/5134817) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6190412/5134817)).

## TeX over 'text'

I have seen a few suggestions about how to do this for some simple plain text, but given the full stop `.` (or possibly also `:`, `?`, `!`, etc.) can appear in maths environments or similar (typically at the end), I am afraid that several of the parsers will introduce huge numbers of breaks.

## Is a parser already out there?

I am happy enough to try a software tool (I know Python and C, but have also seen some Java tools are offered), but a specially designed command line tool I suspect would be ideal. I am tempted to try a `sed` or `awk` parse but suspect there are too many corner cases that I am reluctant to attempt producing my own parser.

## Rules and guidelines

Some of the "guidelines" I suspect the parser should follow are (key requirements emphasised):

- If inside any form of maths mode, probably do nothing. (e.g. several `\!` or similar appear, as well as extensive use of `align` or `gather` environments).
- **If inside a `lstlisting`, then definitely do nothing!**
- If a full stop is proceeded by anything other than a white-space, newline character, or `\\`, probably do nothing. (e.g. `U.S.A`, `2.3kg`, `\footnote{Some sentence.}`., `Dr.\,Brown`, `Downing Jr.`, etc.).
- **If I have already got the next sentence on a new line, don't insert another one**, else this could split a paragraph or break several maths mode environments.
- I often write `something e.g. example` where `e.g.` (also `i.e.`) should "typically" not be line broken, whereas `something etc. Something` typically should be line broken (not always, but if the next letter is a capital then it's very likely). (I also usually have list of examples in brackets, so it reads `something, something else, etc.).`).
- **Doesn't un-comment things**, so if a line reads either
  `% Something is bad. Really bad. To be avoided.`
  or
  `A genuine \tex sentence. % This. is. interesting!`,
  then the comments mustn't be inserted in. (i.e. doesn't change the output).
- Frequently this behaviour should extend to closing `.}`, `.}}`, etc. patterns, but only if the first `}` is preceded immediately by a `.?!:`, although I suspect this is asking too much. (Especially a danger with kerning when using `...\!}` (or `\:}`) inside maths environments).

> **NB - Any processing tool should not change the output of the result** (e.g. a pdf if using `pdflatex`).

PS - I think I have generally used reasonable habits, such as writing `\colon` instead of `:`, put full stops *after* parenthesised sentences, write `\ldots` instead of `...`, etc.

## What's already out there?

- Some python tools for vanilla text, (https://stackoverflow.com/q/4576077/5134817).
- Similarly for Java, (https://stackoverflow.com/q/21430447/5134817).

But as I said, I don't think these were built for TeX/LaTeX, so am worried these will perform poorly.

## Preferences

- Designed with Tex/LaTeX in mind.
- Moderately intelligent so it can handle some/most of the edge cases.
- Stable release.
- Command line friendly.
- User friendly and "easy" to use.

Comment: What's wrong with a Python solution, as in the link you mention (what do you mean by perform poorly)? You can read the tex file and parse it using regular expressions, then save it again.

Comment: @FredericSchneider, The Python solution as linked (using the Natural Language Toolkit `nltk`) would likely be a reasonable attempt, but by performing poorly I am worried about the guidelines I suggested, and that this may alter the output from the tex file.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. All of the rules of thumb you mention are implementable by basically stringing together a bunch of if-conditions. I think it's nearly impossible to anticipate every conceivable exception.

BTW, you should use a backslash after periods that do not end a sentence, for example, "e.g.\ " instead of "e.g. " (otherwise LaTeX will think it's the end of a sentence and will make the space after the period wider than it should).

Comment: I expect it could be built, but with the various LaTeX caveats I was worried anything I put together would be very bug prone (hence the stability in the preferences). Also I hoped maybe something like this for LaTeX already existed, and naturally trust other people usually throw these things together better than I would. Naturally I wouldn't expect anything to have full coverage, but I hope the requirement that the outputs are the same should be sufficient a constraint. (Also, yes, a good spot about `e.g.\ `, which is something I am frequently reminded of when using `\tex` in sentences).

Comment: I wouldn't do this with a batch command python/perl etc, as in that case you have to get the regex completely correct which is tricky to avoid math and verbatim etc, I would just write a trivial regex for full stop followed by space and add newlines and then use emacs (or other editor)  query-replace. OK so you have to hit  y or n a few times but it will take less time than it takes to write a stack exchange question, and you get to check your thesis isn't being scrambled by a bad regex.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I've dug myself fairly deep into this hole, so the thought of checking all the queries sounds very daunting. I would be happy enough to do a simple first pass and perhaps get some of the "low hanging fruit", (likely 90-95%+ of cases) but even so, I suspect there are several gotchas, such as the comments or paragraph splitting. Things like maths modes, verbatim, listings, etc. I would be content to flag as a "no go area".

Comment: Hello! https://github.com/cmhughes/latexindent.pl has a feature that might help with this, https://latexindentpl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/sec-the-m-switch.html#onesentenceperline-modifying-line-breaks-for-sentences I'd be interested to know if this meets your needs :)

Comment: @cmhughes this looks just like what I was after. I’ll try testing it out on some work of mine and see how it performs.

Comment: Great! Let me know how you get on, questions to the repository or otherwise on this site :)

Comment: did you have any success with this?

Comment: It will be one weekend in a few months when I’ll finally give it a go. Takes me a while to get around to things.